# iMac 2011 27" Thunderbolt 2 adapter to connect Thunderbolt 3 hub

Tags: imac, usb, thunderbolt

I have an iMac 27-Inch "Core i5" 2.7 (Mid-2011) and I want to connect a Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) hub via the Thunderbolt 1/2 port.

In all my searching I could only find a [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01MQ26QIY/ref=dp_prsubs_1). The only issue is that I need the opposite, as most of the hubs I have found seem to have a Thunderbolt 3 connector.

So **I am looking for a Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) adapter** that will let me plug the Thunderbolt 2 port into my iMac and connect the Thunderbolt 3 port to a hub like [this](https://www.amazon.ca/Reader-Adapter-MacBook-Surface-Thunderbolt/dp/B07Q6WK8XN/ref=sr_1_56?dchild=1&keywords=thunderbolt%2B2%2Bhub&qid=1606157972&sr=8-56&th=1).

Answer (score 1):

The Apple part is bi-directional, but since the hub you want to work is USB and not Thunderbolt, I would use a much less expensive USB A to USB C adapter to test. You will likely not get the power or signaling to make USB-C 3.0 to work without a proper thunderbolt dock. The adapter you have will let a TB 3 dock work as will the less expensive (perhaps used) Thunderbolt 2 docks like Belkin, Elgato or OWC.

- https://www.macworld.com/article/2920233/thunderbolt-2-docks-roundup-connecting-multiple-devices-to-your-mac-laptop-has-never-been-easier.html

The best way to get USB 3.0 from a TB 2 mac is this part, but it’s not got as many output options as the inexpensive USB-C devices or the proper docks above, but it splits the difference between your hub and the full dock price.

- https://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt3-esata

Answer (score 0):

The Apple TB2 to TB3 adapter is bidirectional but it will only work on docks that are Thunderbolt.  If there is an attached USB-C cable then it will not work with that Apple adapter.  If the dock has any other than a USB-C/TB3 port on it then it will not work with that adapter.  USB 3.x docks will not work.

You will need that TB2 to TB3 adapter, a TB2 cable, and a Thunderbolt dock like this:  https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB3DK14PSL/

As bmike points out you may be able to get by with a cheaper mini-dock that doesn't need the Apple TB2 to TB3 adapter, if your port needs are simple:
https://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-esata

https://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-gigabit-ethernet